# Maradns almost working, but can't get it to dig

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, dig

I have setup the vanilla maradns service and almost got it working but i am missing one thing i think, plz take a look.

**/var/log/messages:**

```
   Sep  2 06:32:13 localhost /usr/local/sbin/maradns: Filename: db.example.net
   Sep  2 06:32:13 localhost /usr/local/sbin/maradns: MaraDNS proudly serves you 21 DNS records
   Sep  2 06:32:13 localhost /usr/local/sbin/maradns: MaraDNS maximum memory  allocation set to 2653696 bytes
   Sep  2 06:32:13 localhost /usr/local/sbin/maradns: Log: All RRs have been loaded
```

**$ sudo netstat -anup**

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           530/chronyd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           24610/maradns
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                530/chronyd
```

**$ askmara Awww.example.com.**

```
 Querying the server with the IP 127.0.0.1
 Remote server said: REFUSED
 NS replies:
 AR replies:
```

**dig @127.0.0.1 example.com ANY**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> @127.0.0.1 example.com ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 46831
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

**Here is the config /etc/mararc:**

> ipv4_bind_addresses = "127.0.0.1"  chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns" csv2 =
>   {} csv2["example.net."] = "db.example.net"

Running centos7, Maradns: 2.0.11, dig: DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 , on amazon-ec2.
Also not setting up recursive server just authoritative dns server. I don't want to setup recursive, if not necessary. 
plz gurus, im lost...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the author can't be bothered to make an intelligible sentence, use proper spelling or punctuation, and also refuses to format the content in a reasonable manner, so it's not a very important question now is it?

Comment: A config file of the service itself would also be helpfull :)

Comment: @wesley, you would think some constructive criticism, considering this is like my third post would be more helpful.

Comment: @inaki i am just using the vanilla. i.e. https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-maradns-on-centos-7/

Comment: Down vote retracted for the effort to clean the post up. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

At first I incurred in the same error (REFUSED), but this configuration works for me, with maradns 2.0.09-2 on ubuntu 16.04 :

contents of file mararc:

```
bind_address = "127.0.0.1"
chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"
csv2 = {}
csv2["example.net."] = "db.example.net"
```

contents of file db.example.net:

```
example.net.      +14400    soa    ns1.example.net. dns@example.net.2012010117 14400 3600 604800 14400 ~  
example.net.      +14400    ns  ns1.example.net. ~  
example.net.      +14400    ns  ns2.example.net. ~  
ns1.example.net.  +14400    a      127.0.0.1 ~ 
ns2.example.net.  +14400    a      127.0.0.1 ~  
example.net.     +14400    a      127.0.0.1 ~  
www.example.net.  +14400    a      127.0.0.1 ~ 
example.net.      +14400    mx     10 mail.example.net. ~ 
mail.example.net. +14400    a      127.0.0.1 ~
```